# How to use Vue 'component' when you only added Vue as a page add-on (<script>)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use a vue component called `vue-timeago`:

```
import VueTimeago from 'vue-timeago'

Vue.use(VueTimeago, {
  name: 'Timeago', // Component name, `Timeago` by default
  locale: undefined, // Default locale
  locales: {
    'zh-CN': require('date-fns/locale/zh_cn'),
    'ja': require('date-fns/locale/ja'),
  }
})
```

However, I didn't built my webapp as a complete Vue app. I used Django's templates function and only added Vue as an add-on on each page:

```
<script>
    let app = new Vue({
        delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
        el: '#app',
        data: {
           
        },
        ...
```

How can I use that component mentioned above? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In theory you may add an attribute `type="module"` to the script tag and then import your component from a file but in this case you should handle all the dependencies manually. Obviously it's hard to do and it would be more practical to use a bundler to automate this part of the work.

I would propose the following steps:

1. Create a source.js that contains:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTimeago from 'vue-timeago'

let app = new Vue({
        delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
        el: '#app',
        components: {
           'Timeago': VueTimeago
        },
        data: {
           
        },
        ...
```

2. Compile source.js into a bundle.js using any bundler of your choice.
3. link bundle.js file on your page:
   `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`